# showing label with ggalluvium

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggalluvial

I tried adding label to a `ggalluvial` plot. I only have axis 1 and 2 and when I try to show label, it shows twice.

Here's my code :

```
ggplot(bdd_1, 
       aes(axis1 = Mef_R21, axis2 = Mef_R22, y=freq, 
           label = scales::percent(round(Effectifs, digits = 2))))+
  geom_alluvium(color= "black",aes(fill=statut)) +
  geom_stratum() +
  geom_text(stat = "stratum", 
            aes(label = after_stat(stratum)),size = 3,discern=FALSE)+
  geom_text(stat = "flow", nudge_x = 0.2, size = 2.5) +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom")
```

and my result :
[image]

I would like to delete the label percentage on the right, outside of the chart (in the red circle on the picture). Is there any possibility to do so?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: which one do you mean? the two label columns in the white boxes to the left of the alluvium labels, or one or the two label columns on the left side of the graph??

Comment: I edited my question to make it clearer. I mean the label in red circle on the picture.

Comment: What about the percentages that appear to the right of the first white column on the  left? Do you want to keep those, but just not for the white column on the right? If you want to remove both, take out geom_text(stat = "flow"....)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to remove both columns with percentages (the "from" and the "to") you can remove the second geom_text() statement. If you want to remove just the column of percentages on the right (the "to"), then here is an approach that involves overriding the data points generated by the plot, effectively setting the values in the "to" column of the flow label to "".

```
## Create a base plot that generates the flow label
g <- ggplot(bdd_1, aes(axis1 = Mef_R21, axis2 = Mef_R22, y=freq, label = scales::percent(round(Effectifs, digits = 2)))) +
   geom_text(stat = "flow", nudge_x = 0.2, size = 2.5) 

## Isolate the data points that are generated for the plot
dat <- ggplot_build(g)$data[[1]] 

## Set the label values to "" where flow is equal to "to"
dat$label[dat$flow == "to"] <- ""

## Run your code for the plot including label = dat$label in the second geom_text().
ggplot(bdd_1, aes(axis1 = Mef_R21, axis2 = Mef_R22, y=freq, label = scales::percent(round(Effectifs, digits = 2))))+
    geom_alluvium(color= "black",aes(fill=statut)) +
    geom_stratum() +
    geom_text(stat = "stratum", aes(label = after_stat(stratum)),size = 3,discern=FALSE)+
    geom_text(stat = "flow",label = dat$label, nudge_x = 0.2, size = 2.5) +
    theme(legend.position = "bottom")
```

[image]

Comment: can I request you to have a look at this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75607765/ggraph-node-color-and-legend-not-matching

Comment: This approach seems to mess up the mappings between flows and labels. E.g. the top most flow is labeled as 5.0% which is clearly wrong.